# Logitech mouse recognised but not functional

Tags: macos, usb, mouse

I'm running version 10.12.6 of macOS Sierra on a 2013 MacBook Pro. I have a Logitech wireless keyboard and mouse combo M310 and K520 which I've been using for a few years. Both work through the same USB receiver as intended when plugged into a Samsung Notebook and PlayStation 4 console, but for whatever reason, only the keyboard works when plugged into the MacBook.

I have the latest Logitech drivers installed, and the Logitech Control Center software recognises that the mouse is switched on, and even knows what level of battery it has:

[image: Logitech control centre recognising mouse]

Despite this, none of the buttons work and moving the mouse doesn't move the cursor.

I've tried:

- Updating the Logitech drivers.
- Switching the mouse off and back on.
- Replacing the battery in the mouse.
- Un-pairing the mouse, restarting the machine and then re-pairing it.
- Un-pairing the keyboard, so only the mouse is paired.
- Plugging the receiver into a different USB port.

This is my work laptop, and at work I use a wireless Microsoft mouse. This does not experience the same issue. The Microsoft IntelliPoint software states "no Microsoft mouse devices found", so I'm certain this driver isn't interfering with the Logitech one.

I've been using this mouse and keyboard combo now for at least 4 years, so I'm really eager to get the mouse working on my MacBook. Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Chances are, your mouse has stopped functioning.  Test it by trying to connect it to a different computer.  If it doesn't work there either, it's time for a new one.

Comment: @Allan I have. It works when connected to my Samsung Notebook and my PlayStation 4. Just to humour myself, I've just retested it on my Samsung Notebook. It's not a problem with the mouse.

Comment: Use [App Cleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) and remove all Logitech software/drivers.  Then try to connect.  You don't need drivers to use the mouse - it should work out of the box.

Comment: Well perhaps the latest drivers don't really work! Have you created a temporary user account on your Mac to make sure it isn't some other setting/configuration/driver in your account which is interfering?

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you so much, @Allan. If you want to add that as an answer I'll happily accept. I spent a good hour Googling yesterday and didn't see this at all as a suggestion. I'm very happy now. :)

Comment: Go ahead and write up the answer.  I'm good on reputation points and I will happily up vote   :-)